# Student ID with total fees

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

> Write a query to display the student's ID and the total fees paid by each student. Give alias name to total fees as TOTAL FEES. Sort the result based on student ID.

It has three tables

1. Course

   Couseid
   Coursename
   Duration
   Fees
2. Student

   Studid
   Firstname
   Lastname
   Street
   City
   DOB
3. Registration

   Courseid
   Studid
   Doj

I have executed the program

```
Select studid,
    (count(courseid)*fees) as total fees
From student
Join registration using(studid)
Join course using (courseid)
Group by studid,fees
Order by studid;
```

Expected result:

```
Studid      totalfees
3001        4000
3002        4000
3003        4000
3004        19000
3005        18000
3006        4000
3007        3000
3008        7000
3009        10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `SUM` aggregate function as follows:

```
SELECT
    STUDID,
    SUM(FEES) AS "TOTAL FEES"
FROM
    REGISTRATION
    JOIN COURSE USING ( COURSEID )
GROUP BY
    STUDID
ORDER BY
    STUDID;
```

**Note**: You can even skip the use of the `STUDENT` table in the query.